# Replacing a string with blank value

Tags: python

I am struggling to write a regex in python As i am new in python i need your help. I have following pattern. I want to replace all the strings till .log with blank is it possible to do it

I want to write a regex which will replace text from "/apps/../......./fgd.log" to blank

```
/apps/fdjg/jhfrdhj/gdjb0/dfhxf1yf/xsrdihg/fgd.log error alert    
/apps/xtf/fdfjkg/l2/jtyg/khiu/njgff/.log warn alert"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is completely unclear. Please take much more space to explain your problem.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  I want to write a regex in python  which will replace "/apps/fdjg/jhfrdhj/gdjb0/dfhxf1yf/xsrdihg/fgd.log " such kind of patterns to blank  and output will only be "error alert " or "warn alert"

Comment: Your problem is still unclear. What do you mean by "such kind of patterns"? Exactly what do you want to become blank and exactly what do you want unchanged?

Comment: @RoryDaulton  From "/apps/fdjg/jhfrdhj/gdjb0/dfhxf1yf/xsrdihg/fgd.log error alert    "  I wan to keep only error alert as an output

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `str.split` with index.

**Ex:**

```
logfile = """/apps/fdjg/jhfrdhj/gdjb0/dfhxf1yf/xsrdihg/fgd.log error alert    
/apps/xtf/fdfjkg/l2/jtyg/khiu/njgff/.log warn alert"""


for line in logfile.splitlines():
    line = " ".join(line.strip().split()[1:])
    print(line)
```

**output:**

```
error alert
warn alert
```